# Password protection of a webcal url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication, webcal

I try to protect the call of a webcal address with a login. Basically it is clear to me how to protect a directory with .htaccess and basic authentication.
But what about the protocol "webcal" and parameters in the URL?

Specifically, I want to protect only this URL:
`webcal://domainname.com/index.php?option=com_jevents&task=icals.export&format=ical&catids=0&years=0&pk=04575786497458993643754733455&i=215`

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can not apply HTTP Auth to the `webcal://` protocol directly. If this is causing the client to make an HTTP request for the equivalent of that URL, then you could protect _that_. If you want to trigger it on specific query string parameters only, then you will have to look for a solution that checks those using SetEnvIf or something; or do it in PHP to begin with.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for the feedback. If I understand it correctly, there are two possibilities.
1. call the link via http
2. use SetEnvIf

What would the codes look like for this?
Thanks

Comment: No, it did not say anything about “calling the link via HTTP”, what I meant was, the application that gets started based on the protocol being `webcal://`, will then probably make an HTTP request to `http://domainname.com/index.php?…` itself, to fetch the actual data. If you put that link onto your site directly instead, then the browser will probably prompt you for where to save this as a download, instead of automatically starting the registered app.

Comment: So you could apply HTTP Auth for that `http://domainname.com/index.php?…` request - but then you’d have to hope, that the actual app that is processing this, understands HTTP auth, and has a way to prompt the user for credentials.

Comment: If you want the authentication to happen in the browser - then you could link to a protected HTTP resource first, which then when proper credentials have been supplied, _redirects_ to `webcal://…`, so that the launch of the associated app only happens afterwards.

Comment: Hi, 
OK, understood.
Maybe the internal redirect, after authentication is a solution. Thanks.
But how would the password protection look like with htaccess, if the URL would be e.g. like https ://domainname.com/index.php?option=com_jevents&task=icals.export&format=ical&catids=0&years=0&pk=04575786497458993643754733455&i=215